# Flutter set Containers height in Column to fit

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, widget, containers

I have simple `ListView` with Custom `Widgets` in it:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: Constants.width(context) / 2.5,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            wishlist.name,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                    bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The problem is that right now I am setting the `Containers` `height` to *200*. But I would like the `Container` to simply fill all the space *that is left*. What is the way to make the `height` dynamically? (from the bottom of my `Text` to the bottom of the whole `Container`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Container` by `Expanded`

PS : Probably you have to add `mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min` to your `Column`